# Border around page is drawing border around full navigation window

Tags: wpf

Just learning WPF and not sure why my page is behaving this way.  I've created a page in which I want to draw a border around the page itself.  It looks right in the designer.  But when I push it to the navigationFrame, the whole navigation pane has the border, not the page.  I need this border just around the page, not the whole navigationFrame.

```
<Page x:Class="com.MyBiz.MyProd.Pages.Configuration.TopLevel.AddCompany"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:com.MyBiz.MyProd.Pages.Configuration.TopLevel"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="400" Margin="0,0,0,30"
      Title="AddCompany">

   <Border BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="2">
      <Grid Background="Gray" Height="250" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

         <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Company Name</Label>
         <TextBox x:Name="tbxCompanyName" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" MaxLength="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,10,0"></TextBox>

         <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Contact</Label>
         <TextBox x:Name="tbxContact" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  MaxLength="500" Margin="0,0,10,0"></TextBox>

         <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Address</Label>
         <TextBox x:Name="tbxAddress" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  MaxLength="100" Margin="0,0,10,0"></TextBox>

         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Width="40" Height="20" Background="LightGray" >
               <Image Source="/Images/cancel.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnCreate" Width="40" Height="20" Background="LightGray" Margin="20,0,0,0" Click="btnCreate_Click">
               <Image Source="/Images/approve.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left"></Image>
            </Button>
         </StackPanel>

      </Grid>
   </Border>

</Page>
```

Comment: Unless you're writing something like a "wizard" and your pages are a series of steps, i would recommend you use a contentcontrol with usercontrols rather than frame/navigation window and pages.

Comment: Haven't seen that yet; looking that up now.

Comment: I can see where I could use this, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve in the app. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a border around your *form*, the `Border` is alright. However, you set a fixed `Width`, `Height`, `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` on your `Grid`, but not on the `Border`. This means, that when your page gets placed in the navigation window, it will scale the `Page` and the `Border` to its full size, while the `Grid` itself will be displayed in a fixed size in the bottom left corner.

It looks like in the image below in the designer. The only reason that it looks right in your designer is that you set the design-time `d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth` to exactly the same dimensions as your `Grid`, which means that the `Page` and also the `Border` have have that size. If you change the design-time size it will look different.

[image]

Now, it is not exactly clear what you want to achieve with drawing a border around the *page*. The page will still be scaled to the size of its container. You can move the sizes and alignments from the `Grid` to the `Border`. Then the page is still scaled to the size of the navigation window and your form will appear in the bottom left corner, but the border will be around it, as it should be.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="2" Height="250" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <Grid Background="Gray">
      <!-- ...your XAML code -->
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

You can also just remove the sizes and alignments completely. Then the form will be sized to the containing navigation window and the border, too.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="2">
   <Grid Background="Gray">
      <!-- ...your XAML code -->
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!